# How to assign a value to public properties from outside of the class in PHP OOP

Tags: php, oop

I want to assign a value to a property of an object. I think it should be something like this:

```
$object->property = "value";
```

So, in my case I do:

```
$circle_obj->radius = 4;
```

So, I expected that property radius should be 4. Unfortunately, this is not the case in my situation. Can you understand why?

Below you can see my code.

```
<?php
    class BaseClass{

        public function calcSurface(){
                //empty method
        }
    }

    class Subclass_Circle extends BaseClass{
        public $radius;

        public function calcSurface(){
            global $radius;
            return M_PI * ($radius * $radius);
       }
    }

    $circle_obj = new Subclass_Circle();
    $circle_obj->radius = 4;
    echo "Oppervlakte van circle is: " . $circle_obj->calcSurface(); //ouput: 0
    echo "<br>";

    class Subclass_Square extends BaseClass{
        public $width;
        public $height;

        public function calcSurface(){
            global $width;
            global $height;

            return $width * $height;
       }
    }

    $square_obj = new Subclass_Square();
    $square_obj->width = 4;
    $square_obj->height = 4;
    echo "Oppervlakte van vierkant is: " . $square_obj->calcSurface(); //output: 0
?>
```

Comment: Delete `global $radius;` instead of `M_PI * ($radius * $radius);` use `M_PI * ($this->radius * $this->radius);`.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `global`, you should be doing `$this->radius` to access local object variables. Same goes for `$this->width` and `$this->height`.

Comment: @Piotr ... jeez that was easy. Almost got it... +1 for right answer.

Comment: http://codepad.org/gVm5RxmE

Comment: And you should make `BaseClass` either abstract or an interface (depending on your needs).

Comment: What would you choose in this case?

Comment: You should understand the difference: [Abstract](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) vs. [Interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) One contains base methods, the other is a contract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `global`, but instead `$this`, like so:

```
public function calcSurface(){
  return M_PI * ($this->radius * $this->radius);
}
```

Check out the [PHP OOP tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) for more information.

And look at the [variable scope tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) to better understand the `global` keyword.